# Control another app's audio playback

Tags: android, audio, listener

I'm trying to write app to control audio playback from another app.

For example: i listen music in google play and my app can intercept control of this audio stream. I dont dont know will it be widget or foreground service with notitication, but i cant find information how to check if music playing in system and how to get access to control it.

I found `MediaSession`, `MediaBrowserService` and so on. But it's implementation about inside one app with creating service to play music background and creating client part as i UI part and gain access to Auto, Google Assistant and so on. But i want to write just client part, take information about currently playing music and write some widget to control it by myself

What can i google to find out the solution?

Comment: There is no requirement for apps to allow you to control those apps' audio playback.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok man, but Microsoft Next Lock Screen can control my musiс playback very well

Comment: and also on play market there some apps that can handle playback from another app. i just want to learn this part of android and it is cool project and experience for me

Comment: I suspect that you have not tested every Android app with audio playback to see whether other apps can control it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with `Service extends NotificationListenerService`

Inside of Service used `MediaSessionManager` and `MediaController`

```
MediaSessionManager mediaSessionManager;
ComponentName componentName;
MediaController controller;

MediaSessionManager.OnActiveSessionsChangedListener sessionsChangedListener = new MediaSessionManager.OnActiveSessionsChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onActiveSessionsChanged(@Nullable List<MediaController> controllers) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActiveSessionsChanged: session is changed");
        for (MediaController controller : controllers) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onActiveSessionsChanged: controller = " + controller.getPackageName());
                MediaMetadata meta = controller.getMetadata();
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: artist = " + meta.getString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: song = " + meta.getString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    componentName = new ComponentName(this, TestMediaService.class);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mediaSessionManager = (MediaSessionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
        mediaSessionManager.addOnActiveSessionsChangedListener(sessionsChangedListener, componentName);

        List<MediaController> controllers = mediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions(componentName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate listener: controllers size = " + controllers.size());
        for (MediaController mediaController : controllers) {
            controller = mediaController;
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: controller = " + controller.getPackageName());
            MediaMetadata meta = controller.getMetadata();
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: artist = " + meta.getString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: song = " + meta.getString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I meet the same question, can you share your solution?

Comment: This requires system permission `MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL` [see link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager#addOnActiveSessionsChangedListener(android.media.session.MediaSessionManager.OnActiveSessionsChangedListener,%20android.content.ComponentName))

Comment: onActiveSessionsChanged not getting called. Please tell me solution.